# Express app, sessions and legal implications

Tags: javascript, express, session, middleware

How do I implement sessions in an Express app, and are there any legal implications of doing so?

1. I've tried googling the answer, but it seems that there are a lot of different approaches. What would you guys recommend for a beginner?
2. I've also heard that there might be some legal issues regarding sessions, so I would appreciate any knowledge you guys may have on that subject.

Thanks in advance

Sam